# How can I interact/output (with) my function's parameters as numbers and not "NaN"?

Tags: javascript, parameters, numbers, nan

So I've received an assignment from my introductory classes to javascript and we're not that far along yet, so I don't have lots of knowledge as of now on the topic, but I'm stuck at this part of the task. The assignment is to make a simple calculator that's able to use the four basic functions (+, -, *, /), to call that function up with two parameters and to output the result. This is the javascript code:

```
"use strict";
var x = document.getElementById('nummer1').value;
var y = document.getElementById('nummer2').value;

function add(p1, p2) {
return Number(p1) + Number(p2);
}

function subtract(p1, p2) {
return p1 - p2;
}

function multiply(p1, p2) {
return p1 * p2;
}

function divide(p1, p2) {
return p1 / p2;
}
```

Now the HTML:

```
<input type="number" name="nr1" id="nummer1">
<input type="number" name="nr2" id="nummer2"><br><br>
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = add(x, y)">Add</button>
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = subtract(x, y)">Subtract</button>
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = multiply(x, y)">Multiply</button>
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = divide(x, y)">Divide</button>
<p>The answer is: <span id="demo"></span></p>
```

Now the problem is that everytime I try to use one of the buttons, the output results in "NaN". I can't seem to figure out why that is. I've made it so that the variables x and y are the values of the user-input and I've specified that they're numbers. I'm not dividing them by zero or anything like that. Shouldn't they just compute normally then? Where am I going wrong? If that makes any difference, I usually put the js code in the head section.

Answer (score 1):

> Now the problem is that everytime I try to use one of the buttons, the
>   output results in "NaN"

because the latest values of `x` and `y` are not taken when you click on those buttons.

Make it

```js
function add() {
  var p1 = document.getElementById('nummer1').value;
  var p2 = document.getElementById('nummer2').value;
  return Number(p1) + Number(p2);
}

function subtract(p1, p2) {
  var p1 = document.getElementById('nummer1').value;
  var p2 = document.getElementById('nummer2').value;
  return p1 - p2;
}

function multiply(p1, p2) {
  var p1 = document.getElementById('nummer1').value;
  var p2 = document.getElementById('nummer2').value;
  return p1 * p2;
}

function divide(p1, p2) {
  var p1 = document.getElementById('nummer1').value;
  var p2 = document.getElementById('nummer2').value;
  return p1 / p2;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" name="nr1" id="nummer1">
<input type="number" name="nr2" id="nummer2"><br><br>
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = add()">Add</button>
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = subtract()">Subtract</button>
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = multiply()">Multiply</button>
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = divide()">Divide</button>
<p>The answer is: <span id="demo"></span></p>
```

Notice that

- `x` and `y` are no longer passed from `onclick` handlers